# Convert PFX to PEM with Key INCLUDING INTERMEDIATE certificates

Tags: ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate

I have a PFX that I want to convert to a CRT and Key or PEM and Key to install on an NGINX endpoint. When I import the pfx to my cert store on my windows machine it creates the certificate, the intermediate chain, and the root CA.

If I take that PFX and run the following openssl commands I and bind it to the endpoint, I don't get all the certificates in the chain:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in ./GoDaddy.pfx -clcerts -nokeys -out pcc.crt -nodes -nokeys

openssl pkcs12 -in ./GoDaddy.pfx -nocerts -nodes -out pcc.rsa -nodes -nokeys
```

Is there a switch or command I can run to convert the PFX to a crt / rsa or pem /key with all of the certificates up the chain to the root CA?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Since you want everything, you just need to reduce the number of restrictions you are asking for.

so:

> openssl pkcs12 -in ./GoDaddy.pfx -out ./GoDaddy.pem

If you read the [documentation](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/pkcs12.html) you will see what you are asking for:

> -nocerts
>
> ```
> No certificates at all will be output.
> ```
>
> -clcerts
>
> ```
> Only output client certificates (not CA certificates).
> ```
>
> -nokeys
>
> ```
> No private keys will be output.
> ```
>
> -nodes
>
> ```
> Don't encrypt the private keys at all.
> ```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I tried it out and it didn't work. I think it might because when I try to create the key: sudo openssl pkcs12 -in ./GoDaddy.pfx -nocerts -out pcc.rsa doesn't work. Is it because it just creates the key for only one of the certs and not the chain?

Comment: Yes the -nocerts will just extract the key only.

Answer (score 4):

You can extract ca-bundle, .crt and .key from .pfx using this.

```
# Extracting ca-certs..."
  openssl pkcs12 -in ${filename}.pfx -nodes -nokeys -cacerts -out ${filename}-ca.crt

# Extracting key file..."
  openssl pkcs12 -in ${filename}.pfx -nocerts -out ${filename}.key

# Extracting crt..."
  openssl pkcs12 -in ${filename}.pfx -clcerts -nokeys -out ${filename}.crt

# combine ca-certs and cert files
  cat  ${filename}.crt ${filename}-ca.crt > ${filename}-full.crt

# Removing passphrase from keyfile"
  openssl rsa -in ${filename}.key -out ${filename}.key
```

Link:
https://gist.github.com/mediaupstream/a2694859b1afa59f26be5e8f6fd4806a